# Ocaml matrix multiplication

Tags: list, matrix, ocaml, matrix-multiplication

hello i am trying to learn ocaml by myself and i am implementing matrix multiplication of list of lists, but i have no clue on how to do it. i am trying to do it without any list functions but it seems like most solutions i have come across use list.map.

this is how i implemented add

```
  let rec m_row r1 r2 =
    match r1,r2 with
      _ -> [] 
    | r1s :: r1',  r2s :: r2' -> r1s + r2s :: m_row r1' r2'
                   

  let rec m_add x y =
    match x,y with
     _ -> []
    | xs :: x', ys :: y' -> m_row xs ys :: m_add x' y'
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Arrays or `Bigarray.Array2` would make more sense than lists, btw.

Comment: @Shawn im trying to implement it using [[1;2;3];[4;5;6]]

Answer (score 3):

You have to split your task into small subtasks and then combine them to get the final program. But before starting coding we have to understand the problem. We represent a matrix as a collection of rows, e.g., a matrix with M rows and N columns is represented as,

```
[[a11; ...; a1N];
 [a21; ...; a2N];
       ...
 [aM1; ...; aMN]]
```

Given some PxQ matrix B,

```
[[b11; ...; b1Q];
 [b21; ...; b2Q];
       ...
 [bP1; ...; bPQ]]
```

we would like to form an MxQ matrix C that is the multiplication of matrices A and B,

```
[[c11; ...; c1Q];
 [c21; ...; c2Q];
       ...
 [cM1; ...; cMQ]]
```

where each element cIJ of the matrix is a cartesian product of row I of the matrix A and column J of the matrix B.

We can conclude that we will need the following primitives to solve our task.

1. `val transpose : matrix -> matrix` the function that will take a list of rows and return a list of columns of that matrix. We will need this because we need to iterate over columns of matrix B.
2. `val product : vector -> vector -> scalar` that we will use to take a row of matrix A and a column of matrix B to obtain an element of matrix C. The product of `[x1; ...; xS]` and `[y1; ...; yS]` is a scalar equal to `x1 * y1 + ... + xS * yS`

Note that I introduce type aliases here, e.g., we can define them as

```
type scalar = int
type vector = scalar list
type matrix = vector list
```

Now we are getting close to the final matrix multiplication procedure. To get a row of the matrix C, we need to iterate over columns of B' (where B' is a transposed matrix B), e.g., `map (product row) columns`, where `columns` is a list of column vectors, which is essentially our matrix B'. Therefore our final matrix C is,

```
[map (product r1) columns;
 map (product r2) columns;
 ....
 map (product rM) columns]
```

which, is a mapping of rows of the matrix A (which is essentially the representation of our matrix A),

```
let mul matA matB = 
  let columns = transpose matB in
  map (fun row -> map (product row) columns) matA
```

where `map f [x1; ...; xM]` is defined as `[f x1; ...; f xM]`